# Assigning PHP Variable to MySQL Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, fetch

I know there is a simple answer but I can't seem to put this together.  I am successfully pulling an array from a MySQL table in the following code, but I would like to assign individual PHP variables to each item.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("$hostname","$username","$password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE state=1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $value=$row['id'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I run this loop I get the output of the id's as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.  How can I go about assigning individual PHP variables to each of these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the variables in an array.

```
$values[] = $row['id'];
```

and then reference it as `$value[0]`, `$value[1]` ...

Also take a look at [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) which allows you to assign individual variables as if they were an array.